# How to Create Apps for SharePoint 2013 in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: 2013, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-addin, apps-development

I have just started to use SharePoint 2013 and I want to create a simple app with VS2012.

How can I create and deploy an apps in SharePoint 2013 step by step? Can anyone provide a quick start guide?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would recommend these links

- Setup the development environment in SharePoint 2013 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx
- Develop in SharePoint 2013 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163085.aspx
- How to create a basic SharePoint hosted App : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142379.aspx
- First Time Configuration For Apps : http://www.mavention.nl/blog/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-install-app-for-sharepoint-app-management-shared-service-proxy-is-not-installed

You should install the VS2012 tools : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apps/fp123627

You can use Office 365 to build SharePoint app either hosted in the cloud or locally (to avoid installing SharePoint 2013 on your dev environment.

Hope it helps !

Comment: Francois,Can you elaborate, how to use office 365 to build SP app hosted in the cloud?